# How to call the module which is not in the same folder in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I am learning one opensource project, the homepage is here: https://github.com/kevsmith/gen_nb_server , I found that the project structure is

```
src/
  gen_nb_server.erl
priv/
  example
    src/
      example.erl
```

when I am going into example folder and run "make", and run the example module by "example:start_link().", it can not find gen_nb_server module, I want to know how to call the module which does not be laid in the same folder ? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use -pa (or -pz) to add the top-level ebin and priv/example/ebin directories to the front (or end) of your code path.

```
# erl -pa gen_nb_server/ebin -pa gen_nb_server/priv/example/ebin
[...]
1> example:start_link().
{ok,<0.33.0>}
```

Comment: thanks!, could you tell me how do you get "gen_nb_server/ebin" directory ? I am just one beginner

Comment: it means, where is the directory-"gen_nb_server/ebin", i can not find it

Comment: it was an alias he used for your project folder. What you write after the `-pa` is a normal path which points at the directory where the beam files are.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what butter71 mentioned.. you can load code while in the shell itself...

```
1> code:add_path("gen_nb_server/ebin").
```

you can also use `code:add_patha` or `code:add_pathz` to load the beam files at the beginning or end of path list..